# Label for y-axis on both sides of a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

Is there an easy way to have two y-axis labels, on both the left and right side of a pgfplots ?

It is possible to create two overlapping axes, however this isn't a nice solution. Is it possible to avoid the creation of a second axis and simply create a new pgfplots key ?

Here is the expected result :

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Left label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,ytick pos=right,ylabel=Right label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it would be different labels. The question is now corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place a second label node using the following key:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    ylabel right/.style={
        after end axis/.append code={
            \node [rotate=90, anchor=north] at (rel axis cs:1,0.5) {#1};
        }   
    }
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    ylabel right/.style={
        after end axis/.append code={
            \node [rotate=90, anchor=north] at (rel axis cs:1,0.5) {#1};
        }   
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Left label, ylabel right=Right label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```