# Is it possible to have xtick and ytick in both side using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I read this link [Label for y-axis on both sides of a pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153792/label-for-y-axis-on-both-sides-of-a-pgfplot) and I would like to check if it possible to have also xtick and ytick in both sides, i.e. the scale numbers. I am using the same MWE as provided in [Label for y-axis on both sides of a pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153792/label-for-y-axis-on-both-sides-of-a-pgfplot).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
ylabel right/.style={
    after end axis/.append code={
        \node [rotate=90, anchor=north] at (rel axis cs:1,0.5) {#1};
    }   
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Left label, ylabel right=Right label]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Left label 
            ]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel=Right label,
y label style={at={(1.12,0.5)},anchor=north},
yticklabel pos=right
            ]
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, congrats!

Comment: What's `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` for?

Comment: @JasonGross, defined with which version of `pgfplotsd` was drawn. today is recent 1.15.